# I can't access of Collection Type Radio Button's values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony4

A basic Form Type in Symfony 4 with "simple fields" (like TextType..) and one CollectionType.

How can I access of Collection Type Radio Button's values in jQuery?

To get the value of "simple field", I do that in jQuery:

```
$('#divfield').click( function() { ... }  );
```

ok no problem

but the same thing with a field that is in collectionType:

```
$('#divInCollectionType').click( function() { ... }  );
```

IMPOSSIBLE , I can't select any div or class that is in data-prototype....

```
FormType "User": 

->add('tel_contact')
->add('struct', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => StructureType::class,
            'data_class' => null,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'prototype' => true,
           ))

FormType "StructureType":

 ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Category::class,
        'choices' => ...,
        'choice_label' => 'nom_cate',
        'expanded' => true,
        'choice_value' => null,
        'attr' => ['class' => 'categories']
    ))
```

I just want, for instance, dynamically display the name of the category checked when the group of radioButton change ... It's so easy but I don't know why with the collectionType it does not work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no element in your collection when your form is displayed, you can't target directly a div from your collection prototype. I suggest you to try something like 
`$(document).on('click', '#divInCollectionType', function() {...})`

Comment: thank's for your answer ! You are right, it's work and if I want to have value of Radio button checked in this '#divInCollectionType', do you have an idea ?

Comment: I guess you can use the same system, but instead of targetting a div, you can target radio button : 
`$(document).on('click', 'input[type=radio]', function () { 
 console.log($(this).val())
})`

Comment: No problem ! Glad to help ! ;)